# Unsorted result in DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using [this](https://datatables.net) plugin. I am using below code

```
$('#elecList').dataTable().fnDestroy();  
$('#elecList tbody').html(electionsItm).promise().done(function(){
    $('#elecList').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
        "pageLength": 10,
    } );
});
```

I am getting sorted result from above code. But I need Unsorted result. Thanks.

Comment: append option `order:[]` to keep initial rows order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
var table = $('#elecList').dataTable();
table.order([]); // set no sorted info
table.draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add order property, column index and sorting order.

```
$('#elecList').dataTable().fnDestroy();  
    $('#elecList tbody').html(electionsItm).promise().done(function(){
        $('#elecList').DataTable( {
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
            "pageLength": 10,
             "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
        } );
    });
```

Comment: `order: [[1, 'desc']]` will *sort* table by the first column in descending order, that's definitely **NOT** *unsorted* result requested by OP